# Device compatibility issue when i download the app

Tags: android

Before publishing my app on Google play store, i testing my app on Micromax A63(Android 4.2) it works accurate but after Publishing when i tried to download my app from Google play store it show "device is not compatible "...whats the reason..I'm confused

Comment: Device not compatible ? Do you have the previous apk installed on the same device ?

Comment: No, I have uninstalled it before downloading it from Google play Store. Actually it also shows same issue on some other devices.

Comment: check your user login of google account

Comment: Your google account and account in the device should be the same

Comment: If your account is not linked with any devices than it will show that device is not compatible ,try downloading it from device play store app or it the second reason may be you have set Maxsdk version in manifest file but I doubt on my second reason

Answer (score 0):

The possible errors are:

1. You had another phone on this account (just check it and make login google play with the correct account)
2. You haven't set correctly something when uploading the apk. Go to the App tab on Google developer console and check if you made available your app for your:

   - Phone Device
   - County
   - Carrier (the mobile network you are paying for your phone service).